# C# Mode in Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010

While configuring my just installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional, I mistakenly opted for Visual Basic mode. I want to correct my selection and change it to C#. How can I do that?

Comment: Who doesn't want Visual Basic mode?!?!

Comment: Good programmers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings > No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings > Take your pick! (i.e. Visual C# Development Settings) > Click Finish

Answer (score 2):

Tools, Import and Export Settings, Reset All Settings.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the "Tools" menu and click "Import and Export Settings"