# Visual Studio 2010 Professional doesn't have C and C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I always program in C# so the last time I installed VS I remember picking C# Mode or something like that. But now, I'm learning C and when I go to new project, C and C++ aren't there at all. What can I do to get these languages back without resetting all of my settings?

[image]

Comment: I remember of reinstalling of VS to do this. Once you start with settings in the beginning, I think you cannot change.

Comment: Perhaps editing installation options when re-running setup will do, too.

Comment: @Mahesh I found this question that tells you how to reset your settings without reinstalling, but i was wondering if thats my only option because I don't want to reset all my settings so that I'll have to change a lot of them back again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929331/c-sharp-mode-in-visual-studio-2010-professional

Comment: Click the "Other Languages" node in the New Project dialog.

Comment: @leaf68 Thanks. I never knew there existed an easy solution like said in the thread :)

Comment: @user946850 Im trying that now. Hans Passant, I already tried that, no luck :( . Mahesh me either :D

Comment: @user946850 check out the screenshot I just posted of the setup, C isnt even on there?

Comment: @leaf68: Then Mahesh might be right. But an uninstall+reinstall should keep your personal settings if they are stored in the Roaming profile.

Comment: @user946850 OK im reinstalling right now

Comment: It finished reinstalling and C is still not on there, BUT C++ is and I just saw a youtube tutorial and the guy clicked on C++ so I'm assuming I just use C++ even when Im writing with C

Comment: @leaf68 You can create a C++ project and write C code in it. But remember to compile it as C code. Please see this [figure](http://imgur.com/oADy3), and select `C` option from the drop down. Its in C/C++ -> Advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was settled in the comments but nobody posted an answer... You just use the `C++` compiler and set the option to compile as `C` code as shown [in this figure by Mahesh.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojNzo.jpg)