# Visual Studio Change from general development settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2010, is there a way to change from `General Development` Settings to `C#` Development Settings?

I forgot to select it when I initially installed it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Mode in Visual Studio 2010 Professional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929331/c-sharp-mode-in-visual-studio-2010-professional)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. click ***Tools***
2. click ***Import and Export Settings***
3. click ***Import Selected Environment Settings***
4. save current settings
5. click ***C#*** under the default setting folder

Comment: If you only want this to apply to the New Project dialog, just select **Generial Settings** –> **New Project Dialog Preferred Language**.

Comment: oh yes yes yes! needed this

Comment: Where does it say which settings are currently in use?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Tools**
2. **Import and Export Settings** > A dialogue box will open.
3. Choose **Reset all settings**
4. Click **Next** > An import and export settings wizard will open
5. Choose **No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings**
6. Click **Next**
7. Click **Finish**
8. Finally click **Close**.