# Cannot create a Windows Forms application in Visual Basic.net in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm not able to créate a new Windows form app with Visual Basic in Visual Studio, as shown in this image.

[image]

According to [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-a-visual-basic-winform-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) I should be able to.

What can be happening that makes the Windows forms template not to appear?

On top of that, I'd likely need it to be in .NET Core, not .NET Framework as in the reference, but I see no reason not to include the same posible template for either C# and Visual Basic.net.

Comment: When Visual Studio first starts up you have an option General, Development, Testing and Project Management. For some of the profiles you do get certain project templates. Try resettting it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31667421/495455 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534183/visual-studio-change-from-general-development-settings

Comment: [Windows Forms Designer and WPF Designer for .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976235/7444103). Follow the other linked answer there. You need to have the Templates installed. Check your VS Installer.

Comment: You're not going to be able to create a WinForms app in VB targeting .NET Core anyway. Even a C# WinForms app doesn't have designer support yet. Everything should be in place by the time .NET 5 arrives but maybe not before that.

Answer (score 1):

Take Visual Studio 2017 as an example, as shown below. Open Visual Studio Installer-> More-> Modify-> Check.Net desktop development-> Modify.
Then restart Visual Studio, check whether it returns to normal at this time.

[image]

[image]

Now you can create New Solution and Project like the follow displayed.

[image]

Please note that for now, unless you use `ASP.NET Core`, you cannot use `Core` in `VB.NET` form applications.