# Visual Studio Startup Development Settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When Visual Studio is launched for the first time, one gets a settings dialog with a drop down to select the `Development Settings` (General, JavaScript, Visual Basic, Visual C#, etc.). This dialog never comes up later. How do I modify the selection under `Development Settings` later?

[image: Visual Studio Startup Settings]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Change from general development settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534183/visual-studio-change-from-general-development-settings)

Answer (score 1):

That drop-down menu lets you choose one of a few preset collections of settings for the entire IDE, which means it does not correspond with any one single setting in the various menus, it actually corresponds with all of them. However, there is still an easy way to revert to one of the presets (while being aware that **this will reset practically all of your IDE settings**):

> ### Reset all settings
>
> You can also use the wizard to reset the environment to one of the
> default collections of settings. Here's how.
>
> 1. From the menu bar, select Tools > Import and Export Settings.
> 2. In the Import and Export Settings Wizard, select Reset all settings, and then select Next.
> 3. On the Save Current Settings page, select either Yes, save my current settings or No, just reset settings, overwriting my current
>    settings, and then select Next.
> 4. On the Choose a Default Collection of Settings page, select a collection, and then select Finish.
> 5. On the Reset Complete page, select Close.

This is taken from [Microsoft's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019), but it would be no mystery if you had difficulty finding this, since they are annoyingly inconsistent in their usage of the terms "Development Settings" and "Environment Settings".